# AutoRemove from list after x time is passed

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I have a chatview where i store + show list of users currently typing.
Server keeps updating this list (add/remove) but i didn't implement any storage for typing users in a group as it is a responsibility of client.

Now if a user disconnects while typing, it cannot send *stopped typing signal* so i want to manually remove a user from list on client side after *x* seconds have passed and the user is still in the list and not been removed since *x* seconds.

Temporary list is not an option as a user could be mistakenly removed if it started typing again like after *x-1 seconds*. How do i implement it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you add a hashmap that wraps your list of users with a timestamp and then periodically check timestamps from the map to remove users from your list?

Comment: Thanks for the timestamp idea. I am surprised why it didn't came to me.